# i am getting nullpointer exception while using session ejb in my managed bean

Tags: jsf, jpa, nullpointerexception

```
my  sessionfacade class

         package com.entity;

         import javax.ejb.Stateless;
         import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
         import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

         @Stateless
         public class UsersFacade extends AbstractFacade<Users> implements UsersFacadeLocal 
         {
         @PersistenceContext(unitName = "My_communityPU")
         private EntityManager em;

         @Override
         protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
         return em;
         }

         public UsersFacade() {
         super(Users.class);
         }

         }



my managed bean class

        package com.jsf;

        import com.entity.Users;
        import com.entity.UsersFacadeLocal;
        import javax.inject.Named;
        import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
        import java.io.Serializable;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Map;
        import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
        import javax.ejb.EJB;
        import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
        import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

        @Named(value = "loginMB")
        @ManagedBean
        @SessionScoped
        public class LoginMB implements Serializable {
        @EJB
        private UsersFacadeLocal usersFacade;



        protected Users user;
        protected List<Users> lusers;
        protected String username;    
        protected String password;

           public LoginMB() {

        lusers=usersFacade.findAll();


           }
          }
```

I dont know why my ejb injection in to mangedbean is not working. I am getting null pointer exception when i am calling findall(); method by using usersFacade 
I am working on netbeans ide with glassfish server. i am just learning jpa in jsf please let me know where i am doing wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Container injects the EJB only after instantiating the managed bean. Use @PostConstruct annotation and use the EJB there. The annotated method will be called after the injection.

Comment: Your answer is right, care to show an example in order to fully help OP?

Comment: hello Luggi MendoZa here is the example how i worked around   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
       if (this.usersFacade.findAll() != null) {
          this.lusers=this.usersFacade.findAll();
       } 
 
    }